# SQL Server cursor loop through columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I don't know how many columns will be there in cursor, so I need to loop through rows and inside that loop I need to loop through columns also.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
JM

Comment: Cursors loop through rows, not columns. They are *not* needed even for that though - SQL, the languge, is set-based. You don't need to loop over rows except in very rare, very advanced scenarios. What are you trying to do? In %99.99 of cases it's easier and a *lot* faster to use a proper query

Comment: It would be best to describe the actual "business" requirement in full. That'll allow more help/guidance to be given.

Comment: You just lost your opportunity for 3 great answers because you didn't really ask a question.

Comment: How could you write a cursor without knowing how many columns? Are you using dynamic sql to generate the cursor?